# wildcard query not working mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, wildcard

I have run the following query on my local database which contains names starting with m,u,e but for some reason this query is returning nothing. I tried to search but didn't find a solution.

**Query:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM umer
WHERE name LIKE  '[MUE]%'
```

*same goes for this query*

```
SELECT * 
FROM umer
WHERE name LIKE  '[e-u]%'
```

Here is the snapshot of my database.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Regards

Comment: Does LIKE support a regular expression? I assume that's what `[e-u]` is, *right*?

Comment: yep it is correct according to mysql standards

Comment: Is your table name umer` ?

Comment: I would have thought the fact it's not working would be a pretty good indication that it's not correct...

Comment: yes table name is umer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As documented under [Pattern Matching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/pattern-matching.html), [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) performs *simple* pattern matching, utilising literals and wildcards only.  It cannot perform complex matches such as you are attempting to do.

However, one can combine multiple such patterns using a logical connective:

```
SELECT * FROM umer WHERE name LIKE 'M%' OR name LIKE 'U%' OR name LIKE 'E%'
```

Or else use [`RLIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) to perform more complex matching against a regular expression:

```
SELECT * FROM umer WHERE name RLIKE '^[MUE]'
```

Comment: ok thanks but what about this `SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE City LIKE '[bsp]%';` query mentioned on W3SCHOOL?

Comment: @Naruto: I believe such patterns are non-standard, proprietary T-SQL extensions which are not supported by MySQL.  Using W3Schools as a source of information is generally a [very bad idea](http://www.w3fools.com/); the [MySQL Reference Manuals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/) are thorough and authoritative - I recommend you refer to those instead.

Answer (score 0):

select col_name from add_kpis where kpi_name rlike '^[tst]'

Comment: Where is `kpi_name`